# How to add selection of (BUS) if I checked the box

Tags: php, sql

[image: Sample]

When checkbox to one code it's take all POST from the dropdown list then insert the code with the last bus into sql
I need to take one choice from the List of bus to one choice from code ?
I don't know if it will be with arrays or what can you help me plz ??

PHP

```
        if(isset($_POST['departments'])){
        $deps=$_POST['departments'];
        echo "<br><br>";
    $sql_q="SELECT code,name,department,job FROM list WHERE department='$deps'";
    $result_q = mysql_query($sql_q);
    echo "<form action= method=POST>";
        echo "<table border=1 width=100%>";
        echo "<tr align=center>";
        echo "<td>Check</td><td>Code</td><td>Name</td><td>Departent</td><td>Job Description</td><td>Bus</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    while($rows_q = mysql_fetch_array($result_q)){
        echo "<tr align=center>";
        echo "<td><input type=checkbox name=type[] value=".$rows_q['code']."/></td><td> ".$rows_q['code']."</td><td> ".$rows_q['name']."</td><td> ".$rows_q['department']."</td><td> ".$rows_q['job']."</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        $sql="SELECT * from bus";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    echo "<select name=bus[]>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<option value=''></option>";
        echo "<option value='" . $row['bus'] . "'>" .$row['bus']."</option>";
    }
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        echo "<input type=hidden name=departments value='$deps'>";
        echo "<input type=submit name=get value='Add Selected' />
    </form>";
        }

      if (isset($_POST["type"]))
      {
                     foreach($_POST['bus'] as $s)
         //===========
        $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM list WHERE code IN(";
         foreach($_POST['type'] as $t)
         {
            $strSQL .="'".$t."',";
         }
         $strSQL=rtrim($strSQL,",").")";
         $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
         while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($objQuery)) 
         {
//=============Insert Single =====================
$entry1=$row['code'];
$entry2=$row['name'];
$entry3=$row['department'];
$entry4=$row['job'];
echo $s;
            $sql = "insert into overtime (code, name, department, job, bus)
VALUES ('$entry1','$entry2','$entry3','$entry4','$s')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {echo "yes";
}else{echo"no";}
         }

       }else{echo "Please Choose At least One";}
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and what you're looking for is a "chained select". There's plenty of examples on this site and all over the rest of the web.

Comment: Bro when i submit with one checked box it takes the code of checked box and insert it with last selected list